# Photos synch google+,picasa,gallery

Tags: nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean, gallery, google-plus, picasa

I'm trying to upload on google+ photos all my old pics so I have it backupped and ordered there, but unfortunatly I encountered some strange behavior.

Here is what I did:

1. Uploaded from my pc with picasa all my album to google+ (checked the date were correct)
2. On Google+ web everything is ok (date and order of the album)
3. On google photos app on my Nexus-4 everything is fine as well.
4. If I go on picasa web album some album have incorrect date (seems they have the date of upload instead the date when pics were taken, but it's the same album on G+!!!)
5. If I synch picasa album in my gallery on Nexus-4 pics have the same problem with date.

Anyone has the same problem?

Also, if I turn off google phots synch and I clear the gallery app data all the picasa album disappear but if I do refresh from gallery they appear again and I didn't turned on google photos synch.

Again anyone with the same problem out there? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that apparently on g+ the albums take the date of the most recent picture of that album, while on picasa web album there is a date for the album, I don't know why but sometimes the date for the album on picasa is the same as the one on g+, others times is simply the date when you created the album.

Anyway it is possible to change that date from the web interface of picasa by selecting an album and editing his property, It's a bit annoying if you have a lot of them but finally now I have all my picasa album properly ordered in my gallery on android. :)